# in what way(s) can we improve estimates of distribution parameters using assumptions about independent measurement errors in the observations?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics

We are doing observations (n=1000) from a population of 40,000 (mean = 3000, sd = 850). Each individual observation done for a sample distribution has an error of +-5%.

Because of the observation error, the standard deviation of our sample distribution is always higher than the population's standard deviation.

Is it possible, knowing the observation error to obtain a sample distribution, that would be as if the sampling error did not exist?

Comment: Just saying that observation 'error' is $\pm 5\%$ doesn't provide necessary distributional information.

Comment: @BruceET For example: If we sampled from a population of 40,000 (mean = 3000, sd = 850). We would get sample = (mean = 2950, sd = 940). The sd is higher because of the error on the individual observations. I am just trying to figure out if there is anything that can be done to reduce the impact that observation error has on the standard deviation.

Comment: Even if you could write a theoretical proof for the dist'n of extra observational error, how would that help to "reduce the impact [of] observation error"? Seems to me fruitful approach would be to try to understand _why_ observations are unexpectedly 'noisy'.

Comment: There is error associated with our hardware that cannot be reduced further. I was just hoping that there was a way we could take the fact that we know our observation error and then say that "When doing 700 observations with an err of +- 5%, the actucal varience of the sample distribution is approximately 20 points less"

Comment: +1 I interpret this question as asking "in what way(s) can we improve estimates of distribution parameters using assumptions about independent measurement errors in the observations?"  You certainly can adjust the estimated variance; it's even possible in special circumstances to go further by deconvolving a density estimate with an assumed measurement distribution.  Is this the sort of analysis you're looking for?  If so, then some judicious edits to your question may dissuade people from voting to close it.  (Welcome to CV.)

Comment: Thanks @whuber. That is exactly what I was trying to ask.